# Modal Segue in WatchKit not calling contextForSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have an InterfaceController with a table view.  I created a segue from a cell of the tableview to another InterfaceController.  If the segue type is "Push" **contextForSegueWithIdentifier** gets called.  If the type is "Modal" **contextForSegueWithIdentifier** does not get called.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind. According to the documentation **contextForSegueWithIdentifier** only gets called on a Push Segue. I needed to use the

`- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex`

method of the tableview to call

```
-(void)presentControllerWithNames:(NSArray *)names contexts:(NSArray *)contexts
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a table view, use this segue method to pass an object to your segue.

```
- (id)contextForSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier inTable:(WKInterfaceTable *)table rowIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    return yourObject;
}
```

Comment: +1. Not sure why this suggestion is downvoted because it's absolutely correct.

If you set up a selection segue in your storyboard, expect this func to fire on your interface controller and NOT the contextForSegueWithIdentifier method. table:didSelectRowAtIndex: isn't going to fire either.

Comment: if you are using modal segue you better user: override func contextsForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> [AnyObject]? {
        return [yourObject]
    }